# Unable to add Event Listener on imported Element Node

Tags: javascript, dom

I am fetching a list of posts from an API and displaying them on webpage. Now, there is a Delete button associated with each post which when clicked should remove the post.

`index.html`

```
    <template id="single-post">
      <li class="post-item">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <button>DELETE</button>
      </li>
    </template>

    <ul class="posts"></ul>
```

`app.js`

```
  const listElement = document.querySelector('.posts');
  const postTemplate = document.getElementById('single-post');

  const listOfPosts = await sendHttpRequest(
    'GET',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  );
  // listOfPosts is already in parsed format

  for (const post of listOfPosts) {
    const postEl = document.importNode(postTemplate.content, true);
    postEl.querySelector('h2').textContent = post.title.toUpperCase();
    postEl.querySelector('p').textContent = post.body;
    listElement.append(postEl);

    const btn = postEl.querySelector('button');
    console.log(btn, postEl);
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      postEl.remove();
    });
  }
```

The above code only fetches first post only and throws

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
> at HTMLButtonElement.fetchPosts

**When I remove the Event Listener, the code works fine.**

I guess this is something to do with `importNode` method since I have done similar things with `createElement` and they worked fine

**EDIT**

I did some little experimenting. The JSON post object returned by API also consisted of an id field. So, I basically added that id to each button that was being created.

Another thing is I used event delegation to remove() the `li` whose button is clicked.

And very surprisingly **It works**

```
  const listElement = document.querySelector('.posts');
  const postTemplate = document.getElementById('single-post');

  const listOfPosts = await sendHttpRequest(
    'GET',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  );
  // listOfPosts is already in parsed format

  for (const post of listOfPosts) {
    const postEl = document.importNode(postTemplate.content, true);
    postEl.querySelector('h2').textContent = post.title.toUpperCase();
    postEl.querySelector('p').textContent = post.body;

    postEl.querySelector('button').id = post.id;   // HERE

    listElement.append(postEl);
}


// delete the li element
listElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
})
```

when clicked on first list post's DELETE button, it consoles

```
<button id="1">DELETE</button>
```

and removes that item.

This bascially proves that the button tag is certainly there since we are able to query select and set its id.
Strangely, when consoled it shows `null`.

Comment: What is the element/node `content` in `postTemplate.content`? Should it not just be `document.importNode(postTemplate, true)`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger We apparantly can't query select the content inside <template> tag directly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content

Answer (score 1):

Your code errors out here:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  postEl.remove();
});
```

The error message clarifies that `btn` is `null`, which means that `postEl.querySelector('button')` returned `null`, which means that there is no `button` tag inside `postEl`.

You will need to carefully look at the result of `document.importNode(postTemplate.content, true)` and see what it contains. You will see that it does not contain a `button` tag. So, either the `button` was not added, in which case you will need to adjust `importNode`, or, the button is not a `button` tag, but something else, like `<input type="button" value="foo">` for example.

Comment: See my **edit**. Apparantly, the button tag is there like it is in the html. I guess the issue bascially is `importNode` because `console.log(postEl)` shows `#document-fragment` which is some special type of HTML content whereas with `createElement`, we console the Element itself.

Comment: @mr.loop please edit your question and post the exact HTML that `document.importNode(postTemplate.content, true)` returned. Without knowing that it is very difficult to determine what happens exactly. Thanks!

Comment: prodEl only consoles `#document-fragment` . There is no information about the element or what it holds etc.

Comment: @mr.loop can you tell me what the value of `postTemplate.content` is?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtkyL.png. And again strangely, the output does not change even when I console it after setting textContent and id. So, that means it is kind of non-live type of reference.

Comment: @mr.loop your images shows that it has a delete button.

Comment: Yes. That delete button is actually inherited from the <template> tag in html.